# Class level decorator

Tags: python, class, decorator

I'm trying to do a sort of type handling function registration, using this code:

```
types = {}
def type_handler(name):
    def wrapper(f):
        types[name] = f
        return f
    return wrapper

@type_handler('a')
def handle_a(a):
    ...

@type_handler('b'):
def handle_b(b):
    ...

def handle(x):
    types[x.name](x)
```

This works fine, but now I want it to work inside a class.
I tried this:

```
class MyClass(object):

    types = {}
    def type_handler(name):
        def wrapper(f):
            types[name] = f ## global name 'types' is undefined
            return f
        return wrapper

    @type_handler('a')
    def handle_a(self, a):
        ...

    @type_handler('b'):
    def handle_b(self, b):
        ...

    def handle(self, x):
        self.types[x.name](self, x)
```

But it says `global name 'types' is undefined`.
I tried changing it to

```
    def type_handler(name):
        def wrapper(f):
            MyClass.types[name] = f ## global name 'MyClass' is undefined
            return f
        return wrapper
```

But now it says `global name 'MyClass' is undefined`.
What can I do to make this work?

I know I can do something like:

```
def handle(self, x):
    self.__getattribute__('handle_%s' % x.name)(self, x)
```

But I prefer function registration rather name based lookup.

Comment: The reason for the behaviour you are seeing is that class scopes are skipped during name lookup – see [The scope of names defined in class block doesn't extend to the methods' blocks. Why is that?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505979/the-scope-of-names-defined-in-class-block-doesnt-extend-to-the-methods-blocks) for further explanations.

Comment: There are several ways to fix this, but I can't really advice on a good way without knowing what the context of this decorator is.  My general recommendation is to use less magic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Sven Marnach. You should use "less magic". However, here is a quick fix:

```
#decorator is declared outside of class and type dict is passed in as an argument
def type_handler(name, type_dict):
    def wrapper(f):
        type_dict[name] = f
        return f
    return wrapper

class MyClass(object):

    types = {}

    @type_handler('a', types)
    def foo_a(self, a):
        pass

    @type_handler('b', types)
    def foo_b(self, b):
        pass
```

**VERSION 2**

This one uses a class as a decorator:

```
class TypeHandler(object):
    def __init__(self, type_dict):
        self.types = type_dict

    def __call__(self, name):
        def wrapper(f):
            self.types[name] = f
            return f
        return wrapper


class MyClass(object):
    types = {}
    thandle = TypeHandler(types)

    @thandle('a')
    def foo_a(self, a):
        pass
```

Comment: This is a bit redundant on the decorator calls.