# Understanding "self" in Python

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7, self

I saw this example from udacity.com :

```
def say_hi():
    return 'hi!'

i = 789

class MyClass(object):

    i = 5

    def prepare(self):
        i = 10
        self.i = 123
        print i

    def say_hi(self):
        return 'Hi there!'

    def say_something(self):
        print say_hi()

    def say_something_else(self):
        print self.say_hi()
```

**output:**

```
>>> print say_hi()
hi!
>>> print i
789
>>> a = MyClass()
>>> a.say_something()
hi!
>>> a.say_something_else()
Hi there!
>>> print a.i
5
>>> a.prepare()
10
>>> print i
789
>>> print a.i
123
```

I understand everything, except why `a.say_something()` equals `hi!` and not `Hi there!`.
That is strange for me, because it calls `say_something()` which is inside the class when it calls `say_hi()` after that. Guess I missed something important..

Comment: Jean-Paul Sartre? I Guess I missed something important (or a good joke) again ;-)

Comment: yes, Kant and Hegel are probably more appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Class scopes aren't considered when looking up a name in enclosing scopes.  You should always qualify with `self.` to get a name from the class scope.

See [The scope of names defined in class block doesn't extend to the methods' blocks. Why is that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505979/the-scope-of-names-defined-in-class-block-doesnt-extend-to-the-methods-blocks) for a more detailed discussion of this behaviour.

Comment: But I thought python looks for an identifier in the local scope first, then in less local scope(and so on) and only then in the global scope. doesn't it ?

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, except for that it skips class scopes, for the reasons discussed in the linked thread.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code:

```
class X:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
  def bound_method(self):
    print "I'm bound to", self.name
  @staticmethod
  def unbound_method():
    print "I have no self!"

x = X("Peter")
x.bound_method()   # prints: I'm bound to Peter
x.unbound_method() # prints: I have no self!
```

Class members and member functions in Python are variables and callables that are *bound to* an object of the class. 
These bound methods receive the object they are called with as their first call parameter, that is usually named `self`.
Referring to bound methods and variables needs to be done explicitly, as in `x.bound_method()`. The object `x` is thereby turned into the first function argument `self`. If you want to access its members, you need to query `self` inside the function.

There are also class methods in Python. That is functions that are not *bound to* a specific instantiation, but are static to the class, see `unbound_method()` for an example.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `a.say_something()` doesn't call class method (it doesn't have `self.` part so it calls global function).

Comment: But I thought python looks for an identifier in the local scope first, then in less local scope(and so on) and only then in the global scope. doesn't it ?

Comment: @Daniel: In classes, `def` defines methods, not functions.

Answer (score 0):

in python to call inner class method you should write `self.` before method name, `self.` means that search class for this method but you don't use self when you call `say_hi()` in `say_something` method and this cause to call `say_hi` function that declared outside of class.
write this to solve problem.

```
def say_something(self):
    print self.say_hi()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's calling `say_hi` from the global scope, rather than the class scope because, within the class scope, there's no such function as `say_hi`, only `self.say_hi`

Maybe this will help:

```
name = 'John'
class Person()

    def __init__(self)
      name = 'Abraham'

    def printName(self)
      print name

>>> pers  = Person()
>>> pers.printName()
   'John'  # uses global name, rather than Abraham, 
           # because Abe is not a class instance variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example will make more sense:

```
def global_scope_hi():
    return 'hi!'

class MyClass(object):

    def class_scope_hi(object_reference):
        return 'Hi there!'

    def say_something(object_reference):
        print global_scope_hi()

    def say_something_else(object_reference):
        print object_reference.class_scope_hi()

a = MyClass()
a.say_something()
a.say_something_else()

>>> hi!
>>> Hi there!
```