# SyntaxError nonlocal python in a method defenition

Tags: python, scope, python-nonlocal

I'm typing in an interactive mode the following code:

```
class A:
    a=42
    def foo():
        nonlocal a
```

but I've a `SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'a' found`. But I'm expected that the result of resolution `nonlocal a` will be 42, because the nearest enclosing scope for this method is a class block.

Comment: I know this doesn't fix your problem, and maybe this is a result of the simplified version of your code here, but couldn't you accomplish the same thing by making ```a``` a class attribute? (referring to it as ```self.a``` and passing ```self``` as an argument to ```foo()```

Comment: @wnnmaw I know that method's code can't access to a class namespace. But I'm interested in how nonlocal does work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class scope are handled in a special way by Python:  When looking for names in ecnlosing scopes, class scopes are skipped.

To access a name from the class scope either use `self.a` to look up via the instance or `A.a` to look up via the class.

See [The scope of names defined in class block doesn't extend to the methods' blocks. Why is that?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9505979/279627) for a rationale for this behaviour.

Comment: That is what I want to know, thanks :). But can you get a referene to a `python reference manual` about names resolution? I can find only `When a name is used in a code block, it is resolved using the nearest enclosing scope.`

Comment: http://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding: "The scope of names defined in a class block is limited to the class block; it does not extend to the code blocks of methods."

Comment: Does it mean that the nearest enclosing scope for `a` defined in the method body is a global namepace (skipping class)?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: Yes, it does.  But `nonlocal` can't be used to refer to names in the global scope.  Use `global` for that (if you really have to).

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is creating a `class` which has a class attribute `a`, with a default value of `42`. You can refer to that attribute by `A.a`. If you want to use it within the class, use `self.a`.

Comment: I believe the OP is not using 2.x. The 2.x error message is `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. The 3.x error message is `SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'a' found`, which is what the OP has.

Comment: @Kevin ah indeed. Sorry about that.