# Why scope of names from a classdef suite is limited to be discluded from closure of a funcdef?

Tags: python, scope, closures, terminology, python-internals

I was expecting a [funcdef](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) to bind the closest inner closure to its definition. Apparently it's not the case:

```
phoo = 4
class Alice: # 'classdef'
  # <class 'suite'>:
  phoo = 1
  spam = phoo + 11
  blah = staticmethod(lambda: phoo + 22)
  @staticmethod
  def Blake():
    return phoo + 33
```

Test:

```
>>> Alice.spam
12
>>> Alice.blah()
26
>>> Alice.Blake()
37
```

It is said that `a code block is executed execution frame`. In the time when the class definition's '[block](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html)' run/executed, `spam` resolves `phoo` from inside `Alice`.

I expected resolution from inside `Blake` to resolve `phoo` from `Alice`. The [execution model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html) says,

> If the definition occurs in a function block, the scope extends to any blocks contained within the defining one, unless a contained block introduces a different binding for the name.

Then it says,

> It is said that `a code block is executed execution frame`.

This decision caused my assumption to go wrong. What is the rationale behind it?

**edit:** this is python 2 old-style classes; but if noted answers can be on new-style classes. I asked for the reason, however if you could add insider technical explanation, it is very welcome too!

Comment: possible duplicate of [The scope of names defined in class block doesn't extend to the methods' blocks. Why is that?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505979/the-scope-of-names-defined-in-class-block-doesnt-extend-to-the-methods-blocks)

Comment: `phoo`, `spam` and `blah` are not "free" variables like it looks like you expect, rather they're bound as attributes to the class `Alice`.  Even inside your `Blake` function, you'll have to use attribute access (`Alice.spam`) to get them (or if `Blake` were a method, `self.spam`).

Comment: Are you asking the technical way that this works under the covers, or the reason why it was designed that way? (Of course those aren't entirely unrelated, but they're definitely not the same question.)

Comment: Also, is this Python 2 or 3? And, if it's 2, are you intentionally asking about old-style classes?

Comment: @abarnert It is Python2. I am deliberately asked about old-style classes, however, I do not know the difference it takes in this respect compared to either new-style classes or Python3, still, I expect those differences might be long enough for separate questions.

Comment: @abarnert I was asking for the reason, howerer, I would very happy to see the technical explanation. I'll edit my question to include that.

Comment: Why did you deliberately ask about old-style classes? You should rarely if ever be using those. And, more importantly, the details for old-style classes aren't really fully documented; to some extent they just "work the way they did in CPython 2.1", while new-style classes are fully designed and specified, which makes them more interesting to ask about…

Comment: @abarnert No problem if the answer goes to new-style classes, if it indicates it. I asked about old-style because I expected that to be closer historically to the making of the decision.

Comment: Well, you're probably right about that… but the details behind the decisions made in the old days are mostly lost to history, except when Guido happens to remember something interesting and write a Python history blog post…

Comment: @naxa: The edit you were trying to make that got lost in a conflicting edit… does that make the footnote actually link to the bottom and back up? If so, I need to learn how to do that.

Comment: @abarnert Too bad but [no](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5362), it was a) `<super>` to `<sup>` and b) `*` to `[1]` to avoid the reader interpreting `locals.*` as (glob-like vague description of) attribute access.

Comment: Oh well. That's still an improvement, so I merged it in manually (and I'll try to remember to stop using the obsolete `super` tag, especially since I think WebKit dropped support for it quite some time ago…). But I was hoping the brackets meant cool linky features. :) (PS, I like the "Plus it looks like you know what you are talking about and therefore encourages upvoting" in that link, even though I secretly just want to be Terry Pratchett. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an intuitive point of view, the answer is pretty simple:

Free variables in a function definition capture variables in the enclosing scope. But class attributes aren't variables, they're class attributes; you have to access them as `Alice.spam` or `self.spam`, not as `spam`. Therefore, `spam` doesn't capture the outer `spam` because there is no outer `spam`.

---

But under the covers, this isn't really true.

For a new-style class, while the class definition's body is being executed, `spam` actually *is* a local variable in the scope of that body; it's only when the metaclass (`type`, in this case) is executed that the class attributes are created from those locals.<sup>[1]</sup>

For an old-style class, it's not completely defined what happens, so you pretty much have to turn to the implementation. In particular, there's no step where the metaclass is executed with the class definition's locals to generate the class object. But for the most part, it works pretty much as if that were the case.

---

So, why *doesn't* `spam` bind to that local?

A free variable can only bind to a closure cell from an outer scope, which is a special kind of local variable. And the compiler only creates a closure cell for a variable in a function definition when a local function accesses it. It doesn't create closure cells for variables in class definitions.

---

So if `spam` doesn't bind to `Alice.spam`, what *does* it bind to? Well, by the usual LEGB rules, if there's no local assignment, and no enclosing cell variable, it's a global.

---

Some of the above may be hard to understand without an example, so:

```
>>> def f():
...     a=1
...     b=2
...     def g():
...         b
...     return g
>>> f.__code__.co_cellvars # cell locals, captured by closures
('b',)
>>> f.__code__.co_varnames # normal locals
('a', 'g')
>>> g = f()
>>> g.__code__.co_freevars # free variables that captured cells
('b',)
>>> class Alice:
...    a=1
...    b=2
...    def f():
...        b
>>> Alice.f.__func__.__code__.co_freevars
()
>>> Alice.f.__func__.__code__.co_varnames
()
>>> Alice.f.__func__.__code__.co_names # loosely, globals
('b',)
```

If you're wondering where `co_cellvars` and the like are specified… well, they're not, but the `inspect` module docs give a brief summary of what they mean.

---

If you understand CPython bytecode, it's also worth calling `dis` on all of these chunks of code to see the instructions used for loading and saving all these variables.

---

So, the big question is, why *doesn't* Python generate cells for class definitions?

Unless Guido remembers, and finds it interesting enough to write a Python history blog post about this, I'm not sure we'll ever know the answer. (You could, of course, try asking him—a comment on his blog or an email to whichever mailing list seems most relevant is probably the best way.)

But here's my guess:

Cells are implemented as indices into an array stored in a code object. When the function is called, its frame gets an matching array of objects. When a local function definition is executed inside that function call, the free variables are bound to references to the cell slots in the frame.

Classes don't have `__code__` members (or, pre-2.6, `co_code`). Why? Because a class definition is executed as soon as it's defined, and never executed again, so why bother? This means there's nowhere to stash a cell, and nothing for it to reference. On top of that, the execution frame always goes away as soon as the execution finishes, because there can't be any external references to it.

Of course you *could* change that: add `__code__` members to classes, create cells in them, and then, if someone closed over those cells, that would keep the frame alive after execution just as it does with functions. Would that be a good idea? I don't know. My guess is that nobody asked the question when Python classes were first being defined. While it's obvious now how much class definitions and function definitions have in common, I think that's an instance of Guido's time machine—he made a design decision without realizing that it would turn out to solve problems nobody would raise until a decade later.

---

<sub>[1] Some of these details may be CPython-specific. For example, I believe it's technically legal for an implementation to make a closure cell for *every* local in a function, or to use some other mechanism that's equivalent to that. For example, if you do `exec('spam=3')` in an inner function, all the language reference says is that it's not guaranteed that it will affect the outer function's `spam`, not that it's guaranteed not to do so.</sub>

Comment: off: is LISP a good toy for better understanding [free variables](http://www.psg.com/~dlamkins/sl/chapter11.html) from a historical perspective?

Comment: @naxa: Yes and no. On the one hand, Lisp free variables are definitely simpler (there's only one kind of scope, and, in Python terms, every local is a cell variable), and they were the inspiration for everything that came later. On the other hand, early versions of Lisp did _dynamic_ scope rather than lexical, which is completely different. But on the third hand, the reasons _why_ Lisp switched from dynamic scope to lexical are well documented and discussed, which is very handy.

Comment: @naxa: Also, of course, earlier Lisps didn't have classes, and Common Lisp's classes are built out of closures, which kind of changes the whole nature of a question like this one…